# HTTP Error 404 when trying to access endpoint of ASP.NET core Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-webapi

I've created a new ASP.NET core Web API project. But when I run it in my development environment it is giving me "`HTTP Error 404. This localhost page can't be found.`". I tried debugging the application by placing several debug points in `Program.cs` and `ServiceExtension.cs` class, but the program control doesn't seem to enter the Controller classes and Service classes.
My `program.cs` is as below:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Including the path for configuration file for the NLog configuration.
LogManager.LoadConfiguration(string.Concat(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "/nlog.config"));

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.ConfigureCors();
builder.Services.ConfigureIISIntegration();
builder.Services.ConfigureLoggerService();
builder.Services.ConfigureSqlContext(builder.Configuration);
builder.Services.ConfigureRepositoryManager();
builder.Services.ConfigureServiceManager(); 
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddApplicationPart(typeof(CompanyEmployees.Presentation.AssemblyReference).Assembly);


var app = builder.Build();
if(app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}
else
{
    app.UseHsts();
}
// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions { ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.All });
app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

The ServiceExtension.cs class is below:

```
namespace CompanyEmployees.Extensions
{
    public static class ServiceExtensions
    {
        public static void ConfigureCors(this IServiceCollection services) =>
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
        options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());
        });

        public static void ConfigureIISIntegration(this IServiceCollection services) =>
            services.Configure<IISOptions>(options =>
            {
                //We are not adding any options becasue we are configuring for default ones
            });

        public static void ConfigureLoggerService(this IServiceCollection services) => services.AddSingleton<ILoggerManager, LoggerManager>();

        public static void ConfigureRepositoryManager(this IServiceCollection services) => services.AddScoped<IRepositoryManager, RepositoryManager>();

        public static void ConfigureServiceManager(this IServiceCollection services) => services.AddScoped<IServiceManager, ServiceManager>();

        public static void ConfigureSqlContext(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration) => services.AddDbContext<RepositoryContext>(opts => opts.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("sqlconnection")));
    } 
}
```

The only controller class is as below:

```
namespace CompanyEmployees.Presentation.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/companies")]
    [ApiController]
    public class CompaniesController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IServiceManager _serviceManager;

        public CompaniesController(IServiceManager serviceManager)
        {
            _serviceManager = serviceManager;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult GetCompanies()
        {
            try
            {
                var companies = _serviceManager.CompanyService.GetAllCompanies(trackChanges: false);
                return Ok(companies);
            }
            catch
            {
                return StatusCode(500, "Internal Server Error");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Does anyone know what is going wrong here? or how can I effectively debug the solution?

Comment: what URL are you navigating to when you get the 404?

Comment: ps. you don't have to catch a general error and return a Statuscode 500, as ASP.net will do all that for you.

Comment: Maybe `builder.Services.AddControllers().AddApplicationPart()` (in `Program.cs`) is not getting passed the assembly where the controllers are located?

Comment: @JHBonarius I tried all possibilites : https://localhost:5000/companies, https://localhost:5000/companies/companies, https://localhost:5000/companies/getcompanies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have decorated you controller with

```
[Route("api/companies")]
```

but in your call you are not including "api".

just call

```
  localhost:5000/api/companies
```

Comment: I don't understand how something as common as this miss my eye. I came across many previous questions with the same url problems and somehow still skipped over them. Thank you for pointing it out.